# How to increase the click area of ​the element without changing the width

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a menu and I came across a problem in css that I haven't thought of how to fix.

There is a problem in the click area due to the width of the **element a**

code:

```js
function OpenMenu(el) {
    
   $(".nav li a").removeClass("active"); 
   $(el).addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: darkgray;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.bar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.bar ul li {
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: gray;
}

.bar ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: red;
      width: 3px;
      height: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
      transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.98, 0.04, 0.25, 1);
}

.bar ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.bar ul li a.active {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    width: 230px;
}

.bar ul li i {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="bar">
         <ul class="nav">
            <li>
               <a href="#" class="active" onclick="OpenMenu(this)">
               <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>
               <span>Test1</span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#" onclick="OpenMenu(this)">
               <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>
               <span>Test2</span>
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
```

problem picture:

[image]

The problem is because of the `.bar ul li a`, having a **width of 3px**.

I did a test using **100% width** and it works correctly.

What should I do to allow the click in the circle area and keep the width at 3px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting `a` tag which is not full width, that's why you are getting this strange artefact. Instead, you can check for hover on parent element `li` and still select `a`, like so:

```js
function OpenMenu(el) {
    
   $(".nav li").removeClass("active"); 
   $(el).addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: darkgray;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.bar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.bar ul li {
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: red;
      width: 3px;
      height: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
      transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.98, 0.04, 0.25, 1);
}

/* Move `:hover` from `a` to `li` */
.bar ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.bar ul li.active a {
    color: white;
    background: red;
    width: 230px;
}

.bar ul li i {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="bar">
         <ul class="nav">
            <li onclick="OpenMenu(this)">
               <a href="#" class="active">
               <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>
               <span>Test1</span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li onclick="OpenMenu(this)">
               <a href="#">
               <i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>
               <span>Test2</span>
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: works fine, just one question is there any way to make it clickable before completing the width of element a ?

Comment: Of course, just move your event listener from `a` element to `li` element and in the css change `.bar ul li a.active` to `.bar ul li.active a` and it should do the thing. EDIT: I have edited the answer, so it should be working as expected now.